# How to manipulate the URL with .htaccess for certain links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, http-status-code-301

How can I manipulate the url by using .htaccess to make the url below work and shorten the size?

I successfully removed the .php, .html extension from the url, but don't have a clue on how to manipulate the character positions and remove the query variable name.

```
Example:
www.website.com/blog?language=en-us
to:
www.website.com/en-us/blog

RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

ErrorDocument 404 /public_html/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /public_html/500.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please do share your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I have successfully removed the .php and .html extension, but don't know how to change the position or query variable name.
```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please add your file in your question in CODE TAGS, thank you.

Comment: I have added a small amount from the .htaccess file, since it won't allow me to upload the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect 301.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(blog)\?language=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
##Internal rewrite to index.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?param1=$1&language=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing me with an example, I will practice and learn to understand it in order to use it to my other links.

Comment: Didn't know about that, just ticked it now. Thanks, I wish you a great day!